# Astro js site inside docker can not be reached from chrome

Tags: docker, astrojs

I'm trying to develop astro.js inside docker.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
    site:
        image: node:lts-bullseye-slim
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        volumes:
            - /project:/project
        command: >
            sh -c
            "
            cd /project
            && npm run install
            && npm run dev &
            tail -f /dev/null
            "
```

And I can see that astro is running inside the docker. I can `curl localhost:3000` from inside the docker container and it shows me the default page of the astro project.

However, when I try to reach `localhost:3000` on my laptop, it gives ms `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error.

What should I do?

**Update**:
`/project` is just a very simple typical `astro` application created with `npx create-astro` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I try to use your docker-compose.yml file then I found some issue as follow.

1. The first time I use "docker-compose up" command and "docker logs my-astro-site_site_1". The logs show "npm run install is not found". so I change content of "docker-compose.yml" from "&& npm run install" to "&& npm install"
   [Container logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cerVy.png)
2. After that when I run "docker-compose up" and log the container. It says "You installed esbuild on another platform than the one you're currently using." because I use M1 and install dependency outside container before start docker compose. so I delete node_modules and package-lock.json and run "docker-compose up"
   [Container logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9LzF.png)
3. Finally I found the same issue that you found "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". It's because you don't expose port when your start with dev. so I change content of "docker-compose.yml" a bit from "&& npm run dev &" to "&& npm run dev -- --host 0.0.0.0 &" and run "docker-compose up". It's work!. My docker compose file look like this:

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
    site:
        image: node:lts-bullseye-slim
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        volumes:
            - /Users/komphet/dev/my-astro-site:/project
        command: >
            sh -c
            "
            cd /project
            && npm install
            && npm run dev -- --host 0.0.0.0 &
            tail -f /dev/null
            "
```

I hope it will be helpful to your software development. Enjoy!

Comment: Such a comprehensive response. Thank you so much. Yes that was my problem that I had to bind to all IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen astro dev on any IP (you need this while running inside docker container) you should add:
`server: { host: true},`

into astro.config.mjs. This will make astro dev server listen on 0.0.0.0.

Adding `--host 0.0.0.0` didn't worked for me.