# Unable to access port Astro app at default port 4321 in Docker container

Tags: docker, astrojs

I have setup the basic Astro skeleton app (with sample data), ran the script "npm run dev" locally and was able to access the site through localhost:4321.

When I tried to create a container from that and ran it, I was unable to access the site at localhost:4321. Below is the Dockerfile I'm using:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4321

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

and the commands I ran to build and run the container (respectively):

```
docker build -t personal-site-astro .
docker run -p 4321:4321 personal-site-astro
```

Comment: It looks like the npm run dev expose the port 3000 internally. Can you try to map 4321:3000 instead ?

Comment: I tried 4321:3000 but still can't access neither on port 4321 nor 3000

Comment: @pedroremedios can you show us how you start your webserver/astro app? I'm not familiar with it, but I've seen issues like this when the webserver is bound on a specific IP and not 0.0.0.0. This might not be your issue, but it's worth checking.

Comment: Does [Astro js site inside docker can not be reached from chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73567964/astro-js-site-inside-docker-can-not-be-reached-from-chrome) have an answer for your question?  It looks like the Astro dev server by default only listens on the container-private localhost interface, and you need to change [`server.host`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/configuration-reference/#serverhost) to make it reachable from outside its own container.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to listen astro dev on any IP (you need this while running inside docker container) you should add:
`server: { host: true},`

into astro.config.mjs. This will make astro dev server listen on 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I forgot I had this question still up. I managed to get it working by using the map 4322:4321. For some reason, Docker on my system doesn't like port 4321.